# Error with DomainAttachDevice method from go-libvirt library: "No secret with id 'libvirt-11-format-encryption-secret0'"

Tags: go, ubuntu, qemu, libvirt, ceph

I'm integrating the digitalocean's [go-libvirt](https://github.com/digitalocean/go-libvirt) library into my Ubuntu environment alongside [Microceph](https://github.com/canonical/microceph). However, when attempting to use DomainAttachDevice, I encounter the error

> unable to execute QEMU command 'blockdev-add': No secret with id
> 'libvirt-11-format-encryption-secret0`

Any advice on resolving this issue would be appreciated. Thank you.